# sitemesh 3 exclude root path

Tags: spring-mvc, sitemesh

when i visit localhost:8080 ， i want to get index.html that is not decorated.
when i visit localhost:8080/admin, i want all the pages to be decorated.

my config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemesh>
  <!--   <mapping path="/" exclude="true"/> not work -->
<mapping path="/index.html" exclude="true"/>
<mapping path="/assets/*" exclude="true"/>  
<mapping path="/admin*" decorator="/WEB-INF/decorators/decorator.html"/>
</sitemesh>
```

index.html isn't decorated unless i visit localhost:8080:index.html

Comment: Did you try 'exclue' instead of 'exclude'? Somehow I see this seems to be the correct attribute name from other examples on the net.

Answer (score 0):

Add   MIME TYPE As  (mime-type) text/jsp (/mime-type).

```
<mapping path="/" exclude="true"/>
```

Kindly Replace Parenthesis with '<' & '>' Respectively .

This will Surely Work.